# Error when I try to assign a value from a table to a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE UserIdToUpdate 

SELECT UserIdToUpdate = customer_id 
FROM dbo.orders
```

I get this error message (translated from the Spanish version):

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> You must declare the scalar variable '@UserIdToUpdate'

Comment: I get this error message: ```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Debe declarar la variable escalar '@UserIdToUpdate'.
```

Comment: Microsoft Server Management studio

Comment: I'm guessing you did not declare the variable with a `DECLARE` statement?

Comment: Do you get the same error after declaring the variable?

Comment: @JNevill I have tried that too: 

DECLARE UserIdToUpdate 
SELECT UserIdToUpdate = customer_id FROM dbo.orders

Comment: @Andrew In the declare i get syntaxis error

Comment: @VicRP9 Stop coding, stop changing things. Post the original and complete script that you run that causes the error.

Comment: I edited the post code, thats all

Comment: I have googled and tried declare, set, select none work

Comment: If i put a semicolon in the end it also gives error

Comment: If you googled, you'd surely have seen that you're missing the datatype?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples

Answer (score 1):

You need first to decalre the user defined varoable before using it

> ```
> CREATE tABLe orders( customer_id INTEGER)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @UserIdToUpdate  INTEGER
> SELECT TOP  1  @UserIdToUpdate = customer_id FROM dbo.orders
> GO
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04f69d7a6bede24eebfb31e926a54202)*

Comment: I tried that without declaring the variable type, was that the error? Thank you so much!